# Why do Replace and ReplaceAll give different results even when only one rule and one expression is used?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Maybe someone can explain to me why `Replace` gives a different answer than `ReplaceAll`, even though I am using one rule, and, I think, I have one expression.

According to the documentation:

```
ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to 
the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no 
further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts
```

and for Replace

```
A list of rules can be given. The rules are tried in order. The result of the first 
one that applies is returned. If none of the rules apply, the original expr is 
returned.
```

I have this expression:

```
z/(0.5 -1.4 z+z^2)
```

and this one rule

```
z -> Exp[I*w]
```

The following input

```
Clear[z]
hz = z/(0.5 - 1.4 z + z^2);
Replace[hz, z -> Exp[I*w]]
ReplaceAll[hz, z -> Exp[I*w]]
```

yields this result:

```
z/(0.5 -1.4 z+z^2)                    (*from Replace*)
E^(I w)/(0.5 -1.4 E^(I w)+E^(2 I w))  (*from ReplaceAll*)
```

So, `ReplaceAll` did the job I expected, but not `Replace`. The only thing I think I am missing here, is what makes Parts of an expression. So maybe hz is not 'one' expression? Ok, fine, but it should then have been able to apply the rule at least to one part of it. But it did not do any replacement anywhere

```
FullForm[hz]
Times[z,Power[Plus[0.5`,Times[-1.4`,z],Power[z,2]],-1]]
```

Isn't hz one expression? If not, how many parts does it have? Is it the number of leaves at the end of the graph generated by `TreeForm[hz]`? If so, then I see 3 'z' in there, and `Replace[]` should then have replaced one of them

[image]

I always used `/.` without thinking about it, which is the same as `ReplaceAll`, but now I used `Replace[]` thinking is was the same as `/.`, I found this and noticed the different functions.
(so many functions to learn, so little time :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact, `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` are *not* the same. You can think of `Replace` as a more precise version, since with `Replace` you can specify the levels in expression on which you want the replacements to happen. The difference here is somewhat similar to that between `Map` and `MapAll`, except the subtlety that `ReplaceAll` does not work depth-first (see below). Another difference, also rather subtle, is that `Replace` takes the `Heads` option, while `ReplaceAll` does not, which makes `Replace` yet more precise than `ReplaceAll`.

By default, `Replace` works *only* at level 0, which is, entire expression. Your `z` is deeper however:

```
In[220]:= Clear[z]
hz = z/(0.5 - 1.4 z + z^2);


Position[hz, z]

Out[222]= {{1}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 1}}
```

If you use the level specification for `Replace`, you can achieve an effect similar to, but not always the same as that of `ReplaceAll`:

```
In[223]:= Replace[hz,z->Exp[I*w],{0,Infinity}]

Out[223]= E^(I w)/(0.5\[VeryThinSpace]-1.4 E^(I w)+E^(2 I w))
```

The difference between `Replace` with lev.spec `{0,Infinity}` and `ReplaceAll` is that the former acts depth-first, sub-expressions before expressions, while the latter works from larger expressions to their parts. It is discussed in more detail e.g. [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node218.html). One example where this difference was used to one's advantage can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/6563973#6563973) post.

Coming back to default behavior of `Replace`, which operates on entire expression: it is very useful when you want to transform only the entire expression, but none of its parts (which may accidentally match the pattern in your rule). One example of such application of `Replace` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234701/how-to-block-symbols-without-evaluating-them/6236264#6236264).

Answer (score 9):

I think the relevant bit of the documentation for `Replace` is: "applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform the entire expression expr. " i.e., to transform the *entire* expression. Thus,

```
Replace[z, z -> Exp[I*w]]
```

would transform `z` to `Exp[I*w]`, but your example fails because the rule does not match the entire expression.

Note that `Replace` takes an argument `level spec`; so to operate on the end leaves of your tree, try

```
Replace[hz, z -> Exp[I*w], -1]
```

giving

```
E^(I w)/(0.5 -1.4 E^(I w)+E^(2 I w))
```