# What is the correct syntax for this ReplaceAll on a list of lists?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

A light-weight question for the experts. I can't seem to figure the correct syntax to this replacement.  I have this list

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
polesList = {{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}};
```

It is of the form of a list with sublists each have the form {order,{x,y}} and I want to generate a new list of this form    (x+y)^order

Currently this is what I do, which works:

```
((#[[2, 1]] + #[[2, 2]])^#[[1]]) & /@ polesList

(* ----->   {(a + b)^3, (c + d)^5}  *)
```

But I have been trying to learn to use `ReplaceAll` as it is more clear to me than pure functions, since I can see the pattern better, like this:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, n]
polesList = {{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}};
ReplaceAll[polesList, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n]   (*I thought this will work*)
```

I get strange result, which is

```
{(5 + c)^3, {(5 + d)^a, (5 + d)^b}}
```

What is the correct syntax to do this replacement using `ReplaceAll` instead of the pure function method?

Thanks

**Update:**

I find that using Replace, instead of `ReplaceAll` works, but need to say {1} at the end:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, n]
polesList = {{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}};
Replace[polesList, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n, {1}]
```

which gives

```
{(a + b)^3, (c + d)^5}
```

But `ReplaceAll` does not take {1} at the end. I am more confused now which to use :)

Comment: I think that `ReplaceAll[expr,rules]` is essentially equivalent to `Replace[expr,rules,Infinity]`.  Replacing at all levels is a more common thing than just at a single level. That's why `ReplaceAll` has a infix form `/.` and `Replace` doesn't.

Comment: Apparently the order that `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` [traverse the expression tree is different](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_10.html). `Replace` starts at the lowest level while `ReplaceAll` starts at the highest.  Compare `Replace[h[f1[a1], f2[e][a2]], (a_ /; Print[a] :> 0), Infinity]` with `ReplaceAll[h[f1[a1], f2[e][a2]], (a_ /; Print[a] :> 0)]`.

Comment: This is why in your case (`polesList = {{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}}`):     `Replace[polesList, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n, Infinity]` works, but `ReplaceAll[polesList, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n]` does not.

Comment: This Leonid's answer is strongly relevant: ["Why do Replace and ReplaceAll give different results even when only one rule and one expression is used?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836790/why-do-replace-and-replaceall-give-different-results-even-when-only-one-rule-and/6836972#6836972)

Comment: @Alexey: I'd even voted up that answer of Leonid... How could I forget his post so quickly?!

Comment: @Simon Perhaps it was not long enough :)

Comment: @Simon Also, thanks for the link. I was unaware of the discussion of `Replace` at Ted Ersek's site (although of course aware of the site itself), otherwise I would have given a link to it in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `ReplaceAll` inspects all levels of the expression when looking for replacements.  The entire expression matches the pattern `{n_, {x_, y_}}` where:

`n` matches `{3, {a, b}}`

`x` matches `5`

`y` matches `{c, d}`

So you end up with `(5 + {c , d}) ^ {3, {a, b}}` which evaluates to the result you see.

There are a few ways to fix this.  First, you can change the pattern so that it does not match the outermost list.  For example, if the `n` values are always integers you could use:

```
ReplaceAll[polesList, {n_Integer, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n]
```

Or, you could use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll`, and restrict the pattern matching the first level only:

```
Replace[polesList, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n, {1}]
```

I find that applying replacement rules to the first level of a list is very common.  It so happens that `Cases`, by default, only operates on that level.  So I find myself frequently using `Cases` for level one replacements when I know that all elements will match the pattern:

```
Cases[polesList, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n]
```

This last expression is how I would probably write the desired replacement.  Keep in mind, though, that if all elements do *not* match the pattern, then the `Cases` approach will drop the mismatches from the result.

Comment: +1 for `Cases` with a `:>`. It's a good construct that I only started using in the last year.

Comment: Thanks. may be I should think of using Replace instead of ReplaceAll and specify the level I want. It is more explicit this way. I forgot about Replace with levels, was just using ReplaceAll.

Comment: I find the `Cases` construct dangerous.  I enjoy terse code, and I am aware of this method, however, I believe that code should be logical, and `Cases` is a filtering function; further, it silently fails (if you are expecting it to match all elements in a list) and that is reason enough for me to avoid using it in regular code.  If `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` are unpalatable for whatever reason, I would use: `f[{n_, {x_, y_}}] := (x + y)^n; f /@ polesList` or similar.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `ReplaceAll` looks at all levels in the expression and the first match to the pattern

```
{n_, {x_, y_}}
```

in the expression `{{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}}` is

```
{ n=={3, {a, b}}, {x==5, y=={c, d}}}
```

(if that notation is clear)

So you got the "strange" result

```
(5 + {c,d})^{3, {a, b}} == {5+c, 5+d}^{3, {a, b}} 
== {(5+c)^3, (5+d)^{a, b}} == {(5+c)^3, {(5+d)^a,(5+d)^b}}
```

**The easiest fix**, if `n` is always numeric, is

```
In[2]:= {{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}} /. {n_?NumericQ, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n
Out[2]= {(a + b)^3, (c + d)^5}
```

Where I used the shorthand `/.` for `ReplaceAll`.

---

**It might be** that using `Replace` at level 1 is the best option

```
In[3]:= Replace[{{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}}, {n_,{x_,y_}}:>(x+y)^n, {1}]
Out[3]= {(a+b)^3,(c+d)^5}
```

which should be compared with the default replace that works at the top level `{0}`

```
In[4]:= Replace[{{3, {a, b}}, {5, {c, d}}}, {n_,{x_,y_}}:>(x+y)^n]
Out[4]= {(5+c)^3,{(5+d)^a,(5+d)^b}}
```

Comment: `Plus@@@polesList[[All, 2]]^polesList[[All, 1]] == {(a + b)^3, (c + d)^5}`

Comment: +1, Just saw your answer, thanks. I see I can use Replace with {1} works, but wanted to see if I can use ReplaceAll. I guess I have to use your solution with NumericQ added to make ReplaceAll work.

Comment: +1, with some minor quibbles... the default level spec for `Replace` is `{0}`, the entire expression.  A level spec of `2` tries replacements on both level 1 and level 2, whereas `{1}` operates only upon level 1 which is what is wanted here

Comment: @WReach: Yeah - I fixed that just before you posted your comment!

Answer (score 8):

You could also use `ReplaceAll[ ]` with Map:

```
Map[ReplaceAll[#, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n] &, polesList]
```

or (using shorthands increasingly)

```
ReplaceAll[#, {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n] & /@ polesList
```

or

```
# /. {n_, {x_, y_}} :> (x + y)^n & /@ polesList
```